# Why does iOS Simulator version 5.1 (272.21) close every time I try to switch to a second view?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

The iOS simulator version 5.1 (272.21) closes every time I press a button to switch views.. any idea why?

```
- (IBAction)SwitchView:(id)sender {
    SecondView *second = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Thats the code for the buton on ViewController.m

Comment: Please show the declaration of `SecondView`.

Comment: What you mean by closing ? Did you mean that your app is exiting ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting on termination ?

Comment: The code works fine for me

Comment: The app is crashing and it does not respond, it freezes, I got "terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)"

Comment: It is single view app, also I get this warning: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: can you show full error message?

Comment: Just check Outlet connection from FileOwner to view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By seeing your code, here is my idea,
If you are using XIB then use this way

```
- (IBAction)SwitchView:(id)sender {
    SecondView *second = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

and if you are not using any XIB use this way..

```
- (IBAction)SwitchView:(id)sender {
    SecondView *second = [[SecondView alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

That might help

Comment: Thing is, it's showing me a thread; it is the following "return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));" signal SIGABRT

Comment: what I can suggest is  
1.)The error in the console usually means you need to restart your device, restart Xcode or restart your Mac. Or some combination of those.
2.)Check for the IBOutlet connections, see if you have defined some object in Xib but they don't exist.
3.)The line UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); just means that an exception was thrown during the running of your program. This could range from a memory problem, to a simple runtime error. Look in the target debugger console;it will tell you where the error occurred.